# Partition LinkedList out of order Python

Tags: python, linked-list, partitioning

For some reason my function to partition a linkedlist return everything partitioned except one node. It only happens when that node data is greater than the pivot number. When it's less it falls right in place. What the heck could be happening? Full code ( with LinkedList and Node classes) below.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def printing(self):
        tempPrint = self.head
        while tempPrint.next is not None:
            print(tempPrint.data)
            tempPrint = tempPrint.next
        print(tempPrint.data)    

    def partition(self, x):
        curr = self.tail = self.head
       
        
        while curr != None:
            temp = curr.next
            #curr.next = None
            if curr.data < x:
                curr.next = self.head
                self.head = curr
            else:
                self.tail.next = curr
                self.tail = curr
            curr = temp
        
        self.tail.next = None
        
        
            
node = LinkedList()
node.head = Node(1)
n1 = node.head
n2 = Node(3)
n3 = Node(2)
n4 = Node(9)
n5 = Node(5)
n6 = Node(1)
n7 = Node(7)
n8 = Node(6)
n1.next = n2
n2.next = n3
n3.next = n4
n4.next = n5
n5.next = n6
n6.next = n7
n7.next = n8


node.partition(5)
node.printing()
```

output = 1 2 3 1 9 5 7 6 ( pivot was 5 )

Comment: When run with a debugger, what is the *first* thing this does wrong?

Comment: When I run it in VSC with debugging it doesn't mention any errors. Just returns the output I put above.

Comment: I didn't ask about errors.  Are you saying every step does exactly what it should, but the final result is still wrong?

Comment: Running VSC debugger still says nothing to debug, Jupyetr notebook is now giving "curr is not defined".  Is that not what "curr = self.tail = self.head" does?

Comment: What do you feel is wrong with the output? The output can be seen as `1 2 3 1` at the left and `9 5 7 6` at  the right. This is fine: all values in the first part are `<5` and all others are `>=5`.

Comment: Thank you trincot! I guess I was assuming the pivot would be in the middle but really my code was putting nodes EQUAL and GREATER than on the right in no particular order which I guess means the 9 can legally be in front of the 5. Right?  I know there code to keep the nodes in order but if they aren't in order the pivot may not be the first   number to start the partition ? I'm curious of others input on this...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was assuming the pivot would be in the middle but really my code was putting nodes EQUAL and GREATER than on the right in no particular order which I guess means the 9 can legally be in front of the 5. So there is nothing wrong with the output.